# Receiving garbled text when attempting to scrape a certain website with Python using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When attempting to scrape [this website](https://www.takealot.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwzNOaBhAcEiwAD7Tb6AhZbkyxR6ewJSUswC-GGcilxY3D10zvFd4repwE3SGZDbVn7U6q4RoC5cwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (TakeAlot) instead of getting normal html output I am instead receiving a little html but mostly garbled text.

Here is what I am receiving:

[image: here is what I am receiving:]

And here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

htmlSource = (requests. Get(
    "https://www.takealot.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwzNOaBhAcEiwAD7Tb6AhZbkyxR6ewJSUswC- 
     GGcilxY3D10zvFd4repwE3SGZDbVn7U6q4RoC5cwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds"
)).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

I'm unsure as to whether I am doing something wrong, or maybe this website somehow blocks scraping?

Either way I would really appreciate any help as to what the issue is. Thanks in advance

Comment: that is not a garbled text. that is an image encoded in base64

Answer (score 0):

As @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan commented, *"that is not a garbled text. that is an image encoded in base64"* - the `href` value of that `link` tag just happens to be that long.

If you wish to quickly view the overall structure of the html tree, you could use `prettify` with this custom [formatter](https://tedboy.github.io/bs4_doc/8_output.html):

```py
def truncateIfLong(str, maxLen=15):
    if type(maxLen) != int: maxLen = 15 # [just in case]
    if maxLen < 4: maxLen = 5
    return str if len(str) < maxLen else str[:maxLen-3]+'...'
```

It will cut any long string down to 15 characters so that

```py
print(soup.prettify(formatter=truncateIfLong))
```

only prints like

[image]

---

However, it's still a huge output to be printing; probably better to save to a file with

```py
with open('x.html', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

and then you can open x.html and view what has been retrieved, without any truncations.